# Is there any way to make HTML button not to use orbitcontrol section cam inside canvas

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, orbitcontrols, valtio

inside glb canvas ..because I have created orbitcontrol camera which makes the html section also to rotate.i need to use orbitcontrol for my mesh not for html function section

I tried to export my html section to separate js file ,but when imported function inside another js also not worked...no luck in state management also

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: iam having glb file in react three fiber named as Canvas.js and i have light cmaera etc inside it and i have written a html section where iam getting error while using orbitcontrol camera the whole html section rotate on it